# ComBox filling SmartGWT

Tags: smartgwt

I have the requirement to enter the data into comboBox after getting the text from TextBox by pressing the add button. How can i get it done in SmartGWT?

Comment: i have taken the text from textItem so far by the following code

Comment: addButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    
   String textValue = textBox.getDisplayValue();
                        
   }
  })

Comment: I  sent the same value to ComboBox by the following code snippet         comboBox.setValue(textValue);          Now i want to fill the comboBox with other values . please suggest so

Comment: are you using DataSource to fill up ComboBoxItem?

Comment: Thanks RAS for your correspondence. I am not using DataSource but aims to fill it otherwise, whatever user will enter in TextItem should come into ComboBox .  Please suggest how this could be achieved.

Comment: Without using Datasource what I suggest is maintain the List of Values (List<String>) somewhere & when you need to add another value, add that value to List & set values to ComboBoxItem again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll want to start by [associating a DataSource](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/ComboBoxItem.html#setOptionDataSource%28com.smartgwt.client.data.DataSource%29) with your ComboBoxItem.  After that, be sure to call both setValueField(...) and setDisplayField(...) on the combo box.  You should start seeing fetch requests get sent when the combo box is instantiated, and the results of the fetch should display in the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

If its not a ComboBox bounded to a datasource its done like this:

```
Map<String, String> valueMap= new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
valueMap.put("key","description");

comboBoxItem.setValueMap(valueMap);
```